# What is predispatch in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

1. I found many times this `preDispatch` function in Magento. I found this function mostly in controller file as a first function.
2. Also sometimes in `config.xml` file.

Anyone, please help me what the purpose of this function in Magento and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 4):

normally an url maps to an action in a controller.
This means that for each url one, and only one, method from a controller is executed.
`preDispatch` is not an action that you can map to an url. it is a method that gets called before executing an "action" method from a controller and it is called for all the actions in that controller.

Comment: if i want to fire an event in controller with `Mage::dispatchEvent`  inside `predispatch` function then that event will fire for each and every action in that  cotroller ??

Comment: yes. Like I said, preDispatch is executed before every action in that controller.